# Cannot select submenus from menubar using SwiftUI on macOS14

Tags: swiftui, menubar, macos-sonoma

I'm trying to add a submenu off one of my menu items using the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MenuAppApp: App 
{
    var body: some Scene 
    {
        WindowGroup 
        {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands
        {
            MyMenu()
        }
    }
}

struct MyMenu: Commands
{
    let array = ["Submenu 1", "Submenu 2", "Submenu 3"]
    @State var selected = "Submenu 1"
    
    var body: some Commands
    {
        CommandMenu("My Menu")
        {
            Button("First Thing")
            {
                print ("First Thing")
            }
            
            Divider()
            Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("Second Thing"))
            {
                ForEach (Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.element)
                { index, item in
                    Text(item).tag(item)
//                    Button(item)
//                    {
//                        print("Button \(item) selected")
//                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selected)
            {
                print ("OnChange \(selected)")
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View 
{
    var body: some View 
    {
        VStack 
        {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This renders the menu correctly but it will not execute the onChange portion of the menu until after the second time of choosing the menu.

Select Second Thing → Submenu 2
Nothing happens
Click once anywhere on the menu bar
It will then print "On Change Submenu 2"

You have to reselect any menu in the menu bar before the action will be executed.

If I uncomment the button code then button action never gets executed.

I also tried moving the selected State var to the top level and then using a binding. This did exactly the same.

How should I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is a custom Binding between `selected` and the picker

```
struct MyMenu: Commands
{
    let array = ["Submenu 1", "Submenu 2", "Submenu 3"]
    @State private var selected = "Submenu 1"
    
    var body: some Commands
    {
        let secondThingBinding = Binding {
            selected
        } set: { newValue in
            selected = newValue
            print ("OnChange \(newValue)")
        }

        CommandMenu("My Menu")
        {
            Button("First Thing")
            {
                print ("First Thing")
            }
            
            Divider()
            Picker(selection: secondThingBinding, label: Text("Second Thing"))
            {
                ForEach (Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.element)
                { index, item in
                    Text(item).tag(item)
//                    Button(item)
//                    {
//                        print("Button \(item) selected")
//                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is curious! It looks like the `.onChange` call’s location is the culprit.

In the code you've given, `onChange` is (on the `Picker`) inside the `CommandMenu`, part of a hierarchy of View instances that only exist while SwiftUI is keeping those views alive. The details of this are not available to us, but from the behaviour we are seeing (that you are only getting the print messages when you click on the menu again), we can infer that SwiftUI probably discarded the entire MyMenu view hierarchy as soon as the "SubMenu X" has been selected. This includes the `.onChange`, and therefore the code that would print your messages.

The solution is very simple. Just put the `.onChange` (and the `selected` state variable) outside the `Commands` struct (I would recommend on the WindowGroup), and use a binding in your MyMenu struct to access `selected`. When the lifetime of the state variable and the `.onChange` closure are tied to a persistent View, the problem goes away. I have tried this and it works for me.

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that this works well. The only problem with it is that it moves the onChange far from the menu code.

Comment: Yes, I can see why you'd want to keep the logic close to the user interface. On the other hand, you could go the other way, and lean into the separation of UI and data (as is encouraged by programming patterns like MVC and MVVM). So in the SwiftUI world, people often have an AppState object, owned by the app, that encapsulates all the state of the app, and some of the "business logic" too.

Comment: By the way, did you mean to mark the custom Binding solution as your preferred answer?